# How do I modify HSQL default schema?

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I am creating HSQL memory db using Hibernate. The connection URL in Hibernate config file looks like this

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mock_db</property>
```

The default name of schema is `Public`. Suppose I want to change that to `TEST`. I have tried this but it didn't change the name of schema.

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">TEST</property>
```

How could I do this? It would be convenient if I could do this in Hibernate configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

Old - To be used for clients written before HSQLDB schema support:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mock_db;default_schema=XXX</property>
```

New - Users may change their base default schema name with the comand:

```
SET INITIAL SCHEMA <schemaname>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a configuration file option, but you can do this after connecting:

```
SET SCHEMA <schemaname>;
```

See http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#set_schema-section

Comment: Unfortunately, this will only change the schema for operations which the SCHEMA is not defined on that JDBC session, it does not create a schema or replaces the public schema

Comment: @Mattos `ALTER USER <username> SET INITIAL SCHEMA <schemaname>;` ???? http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#alter_user-section